# How to make Hand view to verify fingerprint in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I want to make the view with hands as shown in below image in my android app. I want the colors of finger to change if the fingerprint matches. I am using external fingerprint hardware to scan and match finger. any good starting point or guide is useful. I am open to any reference which will serve me as good starting point.

[image]

**Update1**

I am developing for single device having LDPI resolution, but the view looks as follows. how to having the fingers upright, clicks are working fine.

**below is how my view looks like, thumbs looks fine, Now I need to align fingers** 
 [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very difficult to have this kind of layout without fixed size to place finger button.
If you have only one device as target it's more easier.

I did this, with fixed margin to place finger button, my target device was in mdpi, so if your is different margin will not be good.

**layout**:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutHand"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutHandLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="false"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_hand"
                android:src="@drawable/hand_left" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonHandLeftLittle"
                style="@style/custom_button_hand"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_button_hand"
                android:onClick="clickFinger" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonHandLeftRingfinger"
                style="@style/custom_button_hand"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="117dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_button_hand"
                android:onClick="clickFinger" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonHandLeftMiddle"
                style="@style/custom_button_hand"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="61dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_button_hand"
                android:onClick="clickFinger" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonHandLeftForefinger"
                style="@style/custom_button_hand"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="178dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_button_hand"
                android:onClick="clickFinger" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonHandLeftThumb"
                style="@style/custom_button_hand"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="252dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="204dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_button_hand"
                android:onClick="clickFinger" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutHandRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="false"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_hand"
                android:src="@drawable/hand_right" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonHandRightThumb"
                style="@style/custom_button_hand"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="205dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_button_hand"
                android:onClick="clickFinger" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonHandRightForefinger"
                style="@style/custom_button_hand"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_button_hand"
                android:onClick="clickFinger" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonHandRightMiddle"
                style="@style/custom_button_hand"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_button_hand"
                android:onClick="clickFinger" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonHandRightLittle"
                style="@style/custom_button_hand"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="188dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_button_hand"
                android:onClick="clickFinger" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonHandRightRingfinger"
                style="@style/custom_button_hand"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="252dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_button_hand"
                android:onClick="clickFinger" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**drawable/custom_button_hand.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/custom_button_hand_gray"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/custom_button_hand_gray"/>
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/custom_button_hand_gray"/>
    <item  android:drawable="@drawable/custom_button_hand_default"/>

</selector>
```

**drawable/custom_button_hand_default.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:top="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:bottom="10dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/button_default" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**drawable/custom_button_hand_gray.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:top="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:bottom="10dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/button_disabled" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Define in your xml/colors 2 colors button_disabled and button_default.

**Add this style:**

```
<style name="custom_button_hand" parent="@android:drawable/btn_default">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_button_hand</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">48dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">48dp</item>
</style>
```

Both hand images:

[image]
[image]

I create an enum with fingers:

```
public static enum Finger {
        LEFT_THUMB(R.id.buttonHandLeftThumb, (byte) 0x01, true),
        LEFT_FOREFINGER(R.id.buttonHandLeftForefinger, (byte) 0x02, true),
        LEFT_MIDDLE(R.id.buttonHandLeftMiddle, (byte) 0x03, true),
        LEFT_RINGFINGER(R.id.buttonHandLeftRingfinger, (byte) 0x04, true),
        LEFT_LITTLE(R.id.buttonHandLeftLittle, (byte) 0x05, true),
        RIGHT_THUMB(R.id.buttonHandRightThumb, (byte) 0x06, false),
        RIGHT_FOREFINGER(R.id.buttonHandRightForefinger, (byte) 0x07, false),
        RIGHT_MIDDLE(R.id.buttonHandRightMiddle, (byte) 0x08, false),
        RIGHT_RINGFINGER(R.id.buttonHandRightRingfinger, (byte) 0x09, false),
        RIGHT_LITTLE(R.id.buttonHandRightLittle, (byte) 0x0A, false);

        int button;
        byte number;
        boolean left;

        private Finger(int button, byte number, boolean left) {
            this.button = button;
            this.number = number;
            this.left = left;
        }

        protected static Finger getFingerFromButton(int bt) {
            Finger result = null;
            for (Finger finger : Finger.values()) {
                if (finger.button == bt) {
                    result = finger;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        protected static Finger getFingerFromNumber(byte number) {
            Finger result = null;
            for (Finger finger : Finger.values()) {
                if (finger.number == number) {
                    result = finger;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    };
```

And you catch finger button click:

```
public void clickFinger(View v) {
            Finger finger = Finger.getFingerFromButton(v.getId());
            if (finger == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Strange finger not found from button");
            } else {
                currentFinger = finger;

                //launch your action here
            }
    }
```

Comment: will surely try and let you know, by the way I am targeting a single device only. so this might work out.

Comment: what to place in style.xml, for this `style="@style/custom_button_hand"`

Comment: I added the style but result is still the same

Comment: how to place for fingers properly

Comment: It's strange buttons are not round because size is 48x48 in style custom_button_hand. You have with Android Studio layout designer.

Comment: did it, wrapcontent in the layout xml was overriding it.

Comment: So you remove wrap_content on button. Is it work as this ?